# In Turborepo, how to inline internal libraries into an external library build?

Tags: typescript, monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

I'm following the guide https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/publishing-packages/bundling

Turborepo builds my package but it doesn't include the packages that it depends on into the build. Instead, they are in node_modules if the external packages, which isn't very npm publishable.

For example, I'd like to use 'fsm' and 'adapters' inner packages as

```
{
  "name": "myExternalPackage",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "fsm": "workspace:*",
    "adapters": "workspace:*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup src/index.ts --format cjs,esm --dts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsup": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

"fsm" and "adapters" don't end up in the build, despite built index.js referencing them.

How to do? Is it possible that publishing/building npm packages isn't Turborepo' focus?

Are there any other monorepo approaches that I can use, or a good docs/guide on Turporepo somewhere?